# NSTextView inside NSScrollView not co-operating while scrolling

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, nsscrollview, magic-mouse

I have a TableView which has NSTextView as cells.
this is a situation where I have scrollView inside scrollView. Now when I scroll the contents of the textView, and when the textview's content reaches the end, I want the parent scrollView ( the tableView ) to continue scrolling. But by default this does not happen. Instead the parent doesn't scroll at all when the mouse pointer is inside the textView.

[I want to achieve something like in this example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss85A.gif)

This is my solution:

```
public class DisableableScrollView: NSScrollView {

public override func scrollWheel(with event: NSEvent) {

    // Check if the text field is empty
    if (self.subviews[0].subviews[2] as! NSTextView).textStorage?.length == 0 {
        nextResponder?.scrollWheel(with: event)
    }
    // Bottom
    else if self.verticalScroller?.floatValue == 1.00  {
        if event.deltaY < 0 {
            nextResponder?.scrollWheel(with: event)
        }
        else {
            super.scrollWheel(with: event)
        }
    }
    // Top
    else if self.verticalScroller?.floatValue == 0.00  {
        if event.deltaY > 0 {
            nextResponder?.scrollWheel(with: event)
        }
        else {
            super.scrollWheel(with: event)
        }
    }

    else {
        super.scrollWheel(with: event)
    }
}
```

But there is a problem: when I scroll on one text field other text field is scrolling.[click here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T7pI.gif)

Here the problem is with Magic mouse. If I use a normal mighty mouse, everything works fine. But with magic mouse, when I lift my finger after scrolling, it continues to scroll ( momentum scroll ) but scrolls wrong textView instance sometimes. As per [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingTouchEvents/HandlingTouchEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH13-SW9), there are two properties for a scrollwheel event : phase and momentumPhase. With magic mouse after I lift my finger up phase becomes Ended and momentumPhase becomes Began.

Does anyone know a standard solution to this problem?
Or if my code is correct what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem and hence thought of sharing it.

This particular method [wantsForwardedScrollEvents(for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsresponder/1534209-wantsforwardedscrollevents) can be used for forwarding the scroll events up the responder chain whenever the content has reached the end. We just have to override this method and return **true** wherever necessary.

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/views/scroll-views/):

> Don’t place a scroll view inside of another scroll view. Doing so
>   creates an unpredictable interface that’s difficult to control.
>
> In general, display one scroll view at a time. People often make large
>   swipe gestures when scrolling, and it can be hard to avoid interacting
>   with a neighboring scroll view on the same screen. If you need to put
>   two scroll views on one screen, consider allowing them to scroll in
>   different directions so one gesture is less likely to affect both
>   views. For example, when an iPhone is in portrait orientation, the
>   Stocks app shows stock quotes that scroll vertically above
>   company-specific information that scrolls horizontally.

You should rethink Your design.

Comment: Here's the macOS version: [Scroll Views](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/windows-and-views/scroll-views/). It says "Don’t place a scroll view inside of another scroll view. Nested scroll bars create an unpredictable interface that’s difficult to control.".

Comment: I have seen this implementation in Apple's own applications like Radar. But I don't know it is implemented in code.