# Scrolling stops working when an NSTextView is put inside of an NSTableView

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview, nsscrollview

I have an NSTableView and inside each of the table's cell, there is an NSTextView. If my cursor is inside the text views, using two fingers to scroll causes this inner text view to scroll instead of the outer NSTableView. What I want it to do is to scroll the table view when the text view reaches the end of its content (kind of like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss85A.gif)). I stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53829514/7386515) suggesting overriding [wantsForwardedScrollEvents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsresponder/1534209-wantsforwardedscrollevents) and attempted the following:

```swift
class ForwardingScrollView: NSScrollView {
    override func wantsForwardedScrollEvents(for axis: NSEvent.GestureAxis) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. When I set the text views' scroll views to `ForwardingScrollView`, it also causes scrolling to stop working when the text view has *not* reached the end of its content (i.e. scrolling inside the text view does nothing unless you're at the end of the content, in which case scrolling triggers the usual bounce back behavior). When I set the table view's scroll view to `ForwardingScrollView`, the same issue occurs but for the table view instead of the text views (although if both the text view and table view are at the ends of their content, it works). Setting both to `ForwardingScrollView` breaks scrolling completely regardless of where you are.

I feel like I'm missing something really simple here; any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to forward the scroll events when the text view reached the end of its content then you should return `true` if the text view is at the end of its content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSTextView inside NSScrollView not co-operating while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556441/nstextview-inside-nsscrollview-not-co-operating-while-scrolling)

Comment: After randomly trying out different solutions, I found a makeshift solution. It works when the table view's enclosing scroll view is set to ForwardingScrollView, but for some reason only when I set "Show Vertical Scroller" in the storyboard to true. Since I don't want the scroller, I used this line of code to move the scroller off screen: `tableView.enclosingScrollView?.scrollerInsets = NSEdgeInsets.init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: -100)`